# How do I replace the default out of stock message in Oracle Commerce Cloud cart page?

Tags: javascript, oracle, knockout.js, e-commerce

Is there a way to replace out of box message that is default and provided by the platform.?

I need to override the default out of stock message on cart page.

Seems the observable `updatableQuantity` in `cart-item.js` has  the way to display the message. But this file is not accessible.

How do we override the messages in OCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the messages following the path:

> Design > Developer > Text Snippets

Check the [Oracle Commerce Cloud Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97801_01/Cloud.18C/UsingCC/html/s0604customizeyourwebstorestext01.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply go to cart widget and find the text showing out of stock against a key and update the text according to your choice.